# batch wildcard being used as an escaped character when it shouldn't

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

I have a batch which is being called from the windows 7 right click context menu.
Inside the batch I have this code

```
FOR %%t in (avi,mkv,mp4,wmv,ts) do (
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%m in ('DIR /a:d /b ') DO (
        move "%myDir%%%m\*.%%t" "%myDir%"
        pause
    )
)
```

The * is being used as the * rather than a wildcard.
If I manually run the file it works fine the * is used as a wildcard.

Why would this be happening? How do I fix it?
Any help of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What value holds "%myDir%"? what is the current directory in the context of batch file execution? Is it possible that the `DIR` command should indicate the folder to list?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are claiming that `*` isn't working correctly, but - assuming your current directory is `%Mydir%`, it's likely that

```
    move "%myDir%%%m\*.%%t" "%myDir%"
```

should be

```
    move "%myDir%\%%m\*.%%t" "%myDir%"
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP Title is misleading... Why would a wildcard be used as an escape character?

Wildcards work fine within for loops, my money is on %myDir% being the culprint

I recommend using `pushd` and `popd` in these cases to avoid problems with path concatenation

Following code works just fine:

```
@echo off
set dest=%CD%\TargetDir
for %%t in (txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /a:d /b ') Do (
        if not %CD%\%%d == %dest% (
            pushd %%d
            echo Moving %%t files from %%d to %dest%
            move "*.%%t" "%dest%"
            popd
        )
    )
)
```